# Is there an equivalent to GetRouteUrl() at application/class level (.Net 4.8)?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, webforms-routing

Within classic webforms ASPX pages, I create URL routes using the following:

```
var url = this.GetRouteUrl("MyRouteName", new {UserId = 123}); // Generates /UserId/123
```

`MyRouteName` is defined within the `Routes.RegisterRoutes()` method used at startup.

However, I need to generate a URL within a helper method that lives at application-level.  There is obviously no page context there, so I get an error.

The [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.getrouteurl?view=netframework-4.8) states:

> This method is provided for coding convenience. It is equivalent to
>   calling the [RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath(RequestContext,
>   RouteValueDictionary) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.routing.routecollection.getvirtualpath?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Routing_RouteCollection_GetVirtualPath_System_Web_Routing_RequestContext_System_Web_Routing_RouteValueDictionary_). This method converts the object that is
>   passed in routeParameters to a [RouteValueDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.routing.routecollection.getvirtualpath?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Routing_RouteCollection_GetVirtualPath_System_Web_Routing_RequestContext_System_Web_Routing_RouteValueDictionary_) object by using
>   the [RouteValueDictionary.RouteValueDictionary(Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Routing_RouteValueDictionary__ctor_System_Object_) constructor.

I read these, but cannot figure out whether what I need to achieve is possible.  An online search revealed some answers, but these are many years old an not easy to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works to generate the equivalent of `GetRouteUrl` at application/class level:

```
var url = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, 
                                           "MyRouteName", 
                                           new RouteValueDictionary(new { UserId = 123 })).VirtualPath;
```

Remember that only returns a local Url (e.g. /UserId/123) so if you need to domain name you'll have to prepend that as well:

```
var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, 
                                                                                      "MyRouteName", 
                                                                                      new RouteValueDictionary(new { UserId = 123 })).VirtualPath;
```

Answer (score -1):

I have in my Global.asax file in the Application_Start

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Level1", "{lvl1}", "~/Routing.aspx");//Any name will do for the aspx page.
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Level2", "{lvl1}/{*lvl2}", "~/Routing.aspx");
```

Then my Routing.aspx.cs page handles the logic for what will happen with the request.
Mainly I Server.Transfer to an aspx page which will display the requested page.

Routing.aspx page picks up any "non-existing" page.

Hope this helps or at least gives you some more ideas.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I've explained myself properly.  I'm just trying to generate a URL outside a page.  If a page is required then this won't work because I'm operating at application level and not page level.